# JS Closures, Redis, loop, Async :: empty array

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous, redis, closures

I give up on this. May some of the wise stackoverflow monks please fix my bugs?

Code is self explaining. Client sends room names, server does a redis lookup and pushes valid rooms to the array. After adding all the rooms, the list should be emitted to the client.

Problem is closure, async etc. based. I understand the problem but cannot get a workaround because the array needs to remain inside the function. Tricky.

Code:

```
function roomList(socket){

  var roomlist = [], rooms = getRooms(), p = /pChannel_/;

  redis.select(7, function(err,res){

    for (var k in rooms){

      if(rooms[k] != '' && p.test(rooms[k])){

        var key = 'channel:'+rooms[k];

        redis.hgetall(key, function (err, reply) { 

          if(reply){ 
            var c = io.sockets.manager.rooms[rooms[k]];
            roomlist.push( Array(reply['name'],c.length,reply['icon']) );
          }
          else { console.log('nothing found'); }

        });

      }

    }

    // here be dragons
    console.log(roomlist);
    socket.emit('roomList', roomlist);

  });

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'mon guys. The OP explicitly said she/he is interested by understanding how things are supposed to work. And you don't need Q or async or any other 3rd party modules to implement this.

In the initial code, there are two problems:

- with Javascript, the closure scope is at function level, not block level. A function must be introduced to define a proper closure. Here, a simple forEach can be used.
- the final step (i.e. emit) is not run after the replies have been received from Redis. It must be called in the loop itself. In order to achieve it, it is required to count the items so that the inner callback can test whether the process is complete or not.

So here is another version:

```
function roomList(socket){

  var roomlist = [], rooms = getRooms(), p = /pChannel_/;

  redis.select(7, function(err,res){
    var count = rooms.length
    rooms.forEach( function(r) {
      if( r != '' && p.test(r) ) {
        var key = 'channel:'+r
        redis.hgetall(key, function (err, reply) { 
          if(reply) { 
            var c = io.sockets.manager.rooms[r];
            roomlist.push( Array(reply['name'],c.length,reply['icon']) );
          } else {
            console.log('nothing found');
          }
          if ( --count <= 0 ) {
            // here be dragons
            console.log(roomlist);
            socket.emit('roomList', roomlist);
          }
        });
      } else --count;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You guys are kidding?^^ Is counting not a "hack around"? Sure it solves the problem..

Comment: Well, personally, this is what I would use, and this is pure continuation passing style, without relying on any fancy libraries.

Comment: I might have used a `count` approach 5 or 6 years ago but nowadays, no way - at least not unless I was backed into a cold dark corner.

Comment: @DidierSpezia your solution doesn't preserve order, which might – or might not – be a problem. Personally, I find keep track of counts to lead to confusing code. Also, OP states that he understands the problem but is struggling to find an answer. We provided one.

Comment: Something like this doesn't work? `code`reply = function() { return redis.hgetall(key, function (err, reply) {return reply}) }`code` @robertklep The problem is getting the return value from the redis.get function out of it's closure. So counting must be considered as a hack. EDIT: Ok. Not defined in my post.

Comment: @user2429266 that's not how an async workflow works :) something that mimics (up to a point) your example is the use of promises, like Beetroot-Beetroot's solution.

Comment: If that means the common closure examples are not portable to async based functions I accept Didiers Spezia answer. Thanks.

Comment: @robertklep actually, the counting solution does preserve order, because Redis supports pipelining. The replies are always received in the order of the queries.

Comment: No way!!! Install Q. If you're going to program in the node.js environment, then sooner or later you will need it. Node.js is an almost completely asynchronous environment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback):

```
function roomList(socket){
  var rooms = getRooms(), p = /pChannel_/;

  redis.select(7, function(err, res) {
    async.map(rooms, function(room, callback) {
      if (room === '' || ! p.test(room))
        return callback(null, null);

      var key = 'channel:' + room;
      var c   = io.sockets.manager.rooms[room];
      redis.hgetall(key, function (err, reply) {
        if (err)
          callback(err); // propagate Redis errors to final callback, don't know
                         // if you want that or not; use 'callback(null)' if not.
        else
        if (reply)
          callback(err, Array(reply.name, c.length, reply.icon) );
        else
          callback(err, null);
      });
    }, function(err, roomlist) {
      if (err)
         // handle Redis errors...

      // filter 'null' entries from roomlist
      roomlist = roomlist.filter(function(room) { return room !== null });
      console.log(roomlist);
      socket.emit('roomList', roomlist);
    });
  });
}
```

(untested)

Comment: Looks like a good solution but that would just ship me around the process of understanding. I would prefer ways without external methods like map or waterfall. Some pseudocode/hints are fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to wait for the room list to be fully built before emitting the response (as seems highly reasonable), and assuming Q to be available, then you should just need a few additional lines of Q magic plus a closure-forming wrapper around the inner code to maintain a reliable reference to a Q deferred at each pass of the for loop.

```
function roomList(socket) {
    redis.select(7, function(err, res) {
        var list = [],
            rooms = getRooms(),
            p = /pChannel_/,
            promises = [];
        for(var k in rooms) {
            if(rooms[k] != '' && p.test(rooms[k])) {
                (function(dfrd) {
                    promises.push(dfrd.promise);
                    var key = 'channel:' + rooms[k];
                    redis.hgetall(key, function(err, reply) {
                        if(reply) {
                            var c = io.sockets.manager.rooms[rooms[k]];
                            list.push( [reply['name'], c.length, reply['icon']] );
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('nothing found');
                        }
                        dfrd.resolve();
                    });
                })(Q.defer());
            }
        }
        Q.all(promises).then(function() {
            console.log(list);
            socket.emit('roomList', list);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: No Q available. But I see that this situation is a bit more tricky then what I have thought.

Comment: You will struggle without Q or similar.